# Use a dollar sign $ cashtag as well as a hashtag #

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

Ok I'm looking to use both dollar sign $ (cashtag) and a Hashtag # for the following code. The code below is what I've attempted to use...

**This is the ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
// Hashtags and @Mentions
        $str = preg_replace_callback('~([#@])([^\s#@]+)~',
        create_function('$m', '$dir = $m[1] == "#" ? "search/?q=%23" : "./";' .
        'return "<a href=\"$dir$m[2]\">$m[0]</a>";' ),
        $str );
        /* Link text */
        $str = self :: linkText( $str );
        /* Emoticons */
        $str = self :: emoticons( $str );
        $str = stripslashes( $str );
        //$str = str_replace( '&lt;br /&gt;', '<br />', $str );

        //return wordwrap( $str, 60, "\r\n", TRUE );
        return $str;
    }
```

**This is my EDITED VERSION:**

```
// Hashtags and @Mentions
        $str = preg_replace_callback('~([#@$])([^\s#@$]+)~',
        create_function('$m', '$dir = $m[1] == "#" ? "search/?q=%23,%24" : "./";' .
        'return "<a href=\"$dir$m[2]\">$m[0]</a>";' ),
        $str );
/* Link text */
        $str = self :: linkText( $str );
/* Emoticons */
        $str = self :: emoticons( $str );
        $str = stripslashes( $str );
        //$str = str_replace( '&lt;br /&gt;', '<br />', $str );

        //return wordwrap( $str, 60, "\r\n", TRUE );
        return $str;
    }
```

I added the "$" and the %24 to the above code... the thing is that the "*original*" code works properly and produces a URL like this: example.com/search/?q=#myhashtag

BUT with my edited code it shows a URL like this: example.com/myhashtag

How is it possible to have both "#" and "$" function like the original code and produce two URLs like this:

example.com/search/?q=#myhashtag

example.com/search/?q=$mycashtag

Comment: Please could you clearly post what you have before and what you want after. Because, with a code that doesn't work, it is difficult to understand.

Comment: the code at the top WORKS for me and the code at the bottom is my edited code... I am trying to get both "#" and "$" to function like the original code. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unescaped $ symbol in a regular expression will anchor to the end of the input string. To match a literal $ you have to escape it with a backslash